# Get the currently played song in iTunes

Tags: widget, itunes

I'd like to get the name of the song that iTunes is currently playing.
What API should I refer to?

I'd like to use that both for a dashboard widget or a Java/python application depending on what it is easier to use.

Do you have some references for me?

Thanks in advance,
Mario

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an AppleScript that will tell you the information of the currently playing song in iTunes -

```
on run
  set info to ""
  tell application "System Events"
    set num to count (every process whose name is "iTunes")
  end tell
  if num > 0 then
    tell application "iTunes"
      if player state is playing then
        set trackname to name of current track
      end if
    end tell
  end if
  return trackname
end run
```

I hope that helps you in some way!

Comment: Is it possible to get informed about the change song event or do I have to do polling in order to recognize that the song has changed?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're developing for OS X based on the Dashboard widget remark. In that case, the easiest way to interface with iTunes from a Dashboard widget, Python, or Java would be calling AppleScript (see Raphael's code) through an AppleScript library. For Python, [appscript](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/). For Java, [the com.apple.cocoa package](http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.21/21.04/AppleScriptandJava/index.html). And I believe Dashboard widgets can do it by calling the `oascript` command line tool and `widget.system()`.

Comment: How can I tell Eclipse where to find the com.apple.cocoa package?