# Is there a way to find out what song is currently playing in e.g. iTunes using Java?

Tags: java, media-player, itunes, analysis

Is there a way (maybe though RAM analysis) to figure out what song is currently
playing in programs such as iTunes or Windows Media Player?

I'm not asking for any specific code, just interested if there is a possibility to do so, in Java.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010149

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think [JACOB](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/) with the iTunes COM interface would work.

Answer (score 1):

Analyzing the memory of an application sound overly complicated, if not impossible. The correct way to do this would be to talk with an interface the program exposes to the outside world.

If you're working on a Mac, you have the possibility to run an AppleScript to query iTunes what song is playing. I'm certain that there is possible to achieve this in some manner in Windows as well.

Answer (score 1):

iTunes use [Digital Audio Control Protocol (DACP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Audio_Control_Protocol) export functions for remote control iTunes, which is also a bonjour service, means you can pair your client application with iTune server by [zero configuration networking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_configuration_networking) and use DACP protocol access and control iTunes. Fortunately, there are some open source projects written in Java out there implementing DACP protocol, check out [tunesremote-se](http://code.google.com/p/tunesremote-se/).

Windows Media Player use similar technology: [UPnP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play) for zero configuration networking and simple remote control.